# Does IE9 support rounded buttons in css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I know IE8 and below don't support rounded buttons with plain css but does ie9?

Comment: Yes[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144790/does-ie9-support-rounded-buttons-in-css)

Comment: Because it's relevant to your question, the most effective way to give IE9 less than 9 this effect: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: as per @thirtydot's comment - use CSS3Pie to add support for this feature in IE6, IE7 and IE8. IE9 does indeed fully support CSS `border-radius`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a more recent table showing CSS3 properties handled by IE9 but border-radius was already part of them in september: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-support-ie9/

Comment: Looks like it will but can't say for sure as it's still in [Release Candidate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/10/acting-on-feedback-ie9-release-candidate-available-for-download.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's stated aim in releasing IE9 is to support all HTML5, CSS3 and other features which for which finalised specifications have been released.

This means that there are a number of features which Firefox, Chrome, Safari and others support already which IE9 will not support.

The good news for you is that `border-radius` (the CSS3 feature which gives you rounded corners) is fully specified, and as a result, it is implemented in IE9.

I recommend using the site [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/) to check for browser support for individual features. It has a comprehensive list of which browsers support which features.

You may also want to look up [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), which offers a similar service. However although I am a big fan of Quirksmode, it is getting somewhat out of date now. (but it is still a great resource for checking feature support in older versions of IE in particular)